# If a one-to-one function's inverse is the same what must be true of the graph of f?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, inverse

As a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541978/can-the-inverse-of-a-function-be-the-same-as-the-original-function). I'm trying to determine what must be true of the graph of $f$ in these cases. I've examined the two functions $f(x)= x$ and $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ and I'm not seeing any unifying graphic truth. Is there a graphic truth to be found for one-to-one function's where the inverse happens to be the same?

Comment: I think the question asks what happens to the graph of $f$ if $f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$

Comment: Notice that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not the inverse of $x \mapsto x$.

Comment: @Flybynight I don't think anyone is claiming that, rather $x$ and $1/x$ are their own inverses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inversion of the graph corresponds to the operation $U(x,y)=(y,x)$. That is, the graph of the inverse of $f$ is $\{(f(x),x)\}$ (whereas the graph of $f$ is $\{(x,f(x))\}$). It follows that, in terms of graphs, inversion is reflection in the line $x=y$. To see this, consider the action of $U$ on the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$ and compare to the action of reflection in the line $x=y$.

For the function $f(x)=1/x$, consider its [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx%2C+x+from+0+to+10%2C+y+from+0+to+10). This is precisely its own reflection through the [line](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2C+x+from+0+to+10%2C+y+from+0+to+10) $y=x$.

Comment: Yes I see that, and this explains $f(x)=x$ nicely, but what about function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ which does not reflect on the line $y=x$?

Comment: Oh, but it does!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The graphs $y=\mathrm{f}(x)$ and $y=\mathrm{f}^{-1}(x)$ are symmetric about the line $y=x$.

That means, to go from the graph $y=\mathrm{f}(x)$  to the graph $y=\mathrm{f}^{-1}(x)$, you reflect in the line $y=x$.

If the graphs $y=\mathrm{f}(x)$ and $y=\mathrm{f}^{-1}(x)$ are the same then what does that tell you?

Comment: What about function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ which does not reflect on the line $y=x$?

Comment: @James: $f(x)=\frac1x$ *does* reflect onto itself on the line $y=x$. Why do you write otherwise?

Comment: Ok, I get it now.