# How to solve $f(f(x)) = x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Seems simple enough, but I have no idea how one would get *all* solutions to this. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(f(x))%20%3D%20x) gives $5$ answers, the first $2$ of which I could get myself, but the following $3$ completely defeat me.

[image]

Comment: Such functions are known as [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)). In general, given an invertible function $g$, $f(x)=g^{-1}(-g(x))$ is an involution.

Comment: This is simple indeed, only on an entirely _different_ level. There is a great deal of solutions, not just mere 5 or 50.

Comment: I think it would suffice to prove that $f(x)=x$ is the only solution of this functional equation.

Comment: At first I thought the question was how to solve $f(f(x) = x$ for $x$.  Obviously that depends on $f$!  Now I understand the question is how to solve $f \circ f = \text{Id}$ for $f$, which is definitely nontrivial.

Comment: @ShreyAryan But it isn't. Depending on the domain of $f$ there are other solutions (and $\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$ is a solution on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: interesting question (+1)

Comment: notice also that solutions one and two are special cases of the solution 3

Comment: [Involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29). Related MSE questions: [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541978/can-the-inverse-of-a-function-be-the-same-as-the-original-function), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356095/functions-that-are-their-own-inversion)

Comment: Yeah, I thought this **must** have been asked before. So in fact, this question is a duplicate, and so is my answer (both halves of it). There were many before it. Wonder why the "Related" column didn't put them forth.

Comment: Even $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ satisfies it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a ***continuous solution***:

1. Draw a graph of $y=x$ (this is an auxiliary construction, you will erase it later).
2. Starting at any point on the graph, draw a **freehand** graph of a decreasing function.
3. Draw the *reflection* of that graph with respect to the line $y=x$.
4. Erase the line $y=x$. What remains is the graph of your function.

If you want ***just any solution***:

1. Select two arbitrary non-intersecting [equinumerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity) sets $A,B\in\mathbb R$. (They can be empty, or finite, or countably infinite, or uncountably infinite; that doesn't matter.)
2. Select any [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) $A\leftrightarrow B$.
3. For any $x\in A$, let $f(x)$ be the image of $x$ in $B$ under that bijection, and vice versa.
4. For any $x\in\mathbb R\setminus(A\cup B)$, let $f(x)=x$.