# $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $f(f(x))=x$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be such that $f(f(x))=x$, for all $x\in X$.
>
> Then $f$
>
> 1. is one-one and onto;
> 2. is one-one but not onto;
> 3. is onto but not one-one;
> 4. need not be either.

From the given condition I have that $f^2=i$ where $i$ is the identity function. If $f$ itself is the identity function then the conditions are satisfied as well as $f$ is bijection. Is that the only such function or are there other possibilities ?

My guess is that it will be bijection i.e. option $1$ will be correct .

For see, if $$f(x_1)=y \ \text{and}\ f(x_2)=y \ \text{then} \ f(y)=x_1\ \text{and}\ f(y)=x_2$$ will be possible iff $x_1=x_2$. So this is injective.

Now an injection from a set to itself is trivially surjective so it is bijective.   Is my proof correct?

Comment: $\exp(x)$ is injective $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but is not surjective

Comment: Lots of opitions.  f (x)=-x.  f (x) = 1/x;if n!=0,f (x)=0;if x=0.  For {q_i} any enumeration of the rationals f (q_2k)= 2k+1, while f (q_2k+1)= q_2k for rational f (x)=1/x if x irrational, etc.

Comment: You proof of injective is good.  Surjective not.

Comment: If $ X $ is finite, then the injectivity of $ f $ implies the surjectivity of $ f $ also. However, when $ X $ is infinite, this is no longer necessarily true.

Comment: For surjective: Obviously $X = i(X) = f(f(X))\subseteq f(X)\subseteq X$.

Comment: A few post with examples of such functions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356095/functions-that-are-their-own-inversion 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541978/can-the-inverse-of-a-function-be-the-same-as-the-original-function
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46635/examples-of-involutions-on-mathbbr (and many other - just look on the posts shown as linked or related to those posts)

Comment: Note that the metric is completely irrelevant in this statement.

Answer (score 5):

Injective.

If $f (x)=f (y) $ then $x=f (f (x))=f (f (y)l=y $, so injective.

Surjective:

If $y \in X $.  Then $f (y)=x \in X $.  So $f (x)=f (f (y))=y $, so surjective.

It really is that simple.

===

But there's more than just f =identity.  Lots more.

Pick any such $f$ and any $a,b;a\ne b $ and define $g (a)=b, g (b)=a; g(x)=f (x)$ if $x \ne a;x\ne b $.

Here's a convoluted one.  Let $\{q_i\} $ be any enumeration of the rational numbers.  Let $f (q_{2k})=q_{2k+1};f (q_{2k+1})=q_{2k} $ and $f (x)=- 1/x $ otherwise.

Or if $x = a_ia_{i-1}....a_0.b_1b_2.... $ be the decimal expansion of $x$ Let f:R to R, map each decimal digit (except the leading digit if it happens to be $5$) to the digit plus or minus $5$.  (Example: $f (\pi)= f(3.141592653.....)=  8.696047108....)$ and $f (52 \frac 18)=f(52.125) =57.67055555555555..... = 57\frac {1,207}{1,800}$)

I got a million of them.

Comment: I don't understand the second example, how the mapping is defined?

Comment: I had a hard time rereading the second example 7 years later too.  But $f: a_ia{i=1}...a_{0}.b_2b_2..... \to(\begin{cases}a_0&a_0=5\\a_0+5\pmod{10}&a_0\ne 5\\\end{cases} )(a_{i-1}+5\pmod{10})...(a_0+5\pmod{10}).(b_1+5\pmod{10})(b_2+5\pmod{10})....$           Basically you are just shifting every digit by 5 (unless the leading digit happens to be five andwe don't want to shift it to $0$ [else we'd have $f(59)=04$ and $f(4)=9$ and $f(f(59))\ne 59$])

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For *any* two functions $f:Y\to Z$ and $g:X\to Y$, can

1. $f\circ g$ be onto if $g$ isn't?
2. $f\circ g$ be one-to-one if $f$ isn't?

Comment: thank you . but my proof is correct is not it?

Comment: An injection from a set to itself is only bijective iff said set is finite (in fact, that's one way to _define_ "finite set"). So you need to check surjectivity on its own.

Comment: I know. $y$ is the image of $f(y)$ right?

Comment: @user118494 Your proof is not correct as a number of people have pointed out already. There are many injections from a set into itself which are not surjective. They can even be extremely unsurjective consider $\epsilon \arctan(x)$. What do you mean by $y$ is the image of $f(y)$. if you're saying $f(f(y))=y$ that's just your premise. If you're saying $f(y)=y$ than that is not necessarily true.

Comment: @DRF : I meant $y$  is image of $f(y)$  in just this onr case where $f(f(y))=y$  is given that's all. Not for general cases.

Comment: @user118494 Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

*An injection from a set to itself is trivially surjective*. No, It is only true for finite sets:

$$\begin{align}f:&\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N \\
&n \mapsto2n\end{align}$$ is trivially injective and not surjective

So you must also prove that your application is surjective. But it is equally simple: $\forall x \in X, y = f(x) \space\mathrm{verifies}\space f(y) = f(f(x)) = x$

Answer (score 0):

You have already been explained why your proof is not correct.

Now, the hypothesis rewrites
$$f\circ f={\rm id}_X,$$
i.e. $f$ is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)). It is therefore a bijection. Indeed, more generally:

> A map $f:X\to Y$ is bijective if (and only if) there exists a map $g:Y\to X$ such that
> $$g\circ f={\rm id}_X\quad\text{and}\quad f\circ g={\rm id}_Y.$$

This sufficient condition can even be weakened, thereby becoming a variant of @Arthur 's answer:

> A map $f:X\to Y$ is bijective if (and only if) there exist maps $g:Y\to Z$ and $h:T\to X$ such that
> $$g\circ f\text{ is one-to-one}\quad\text{and}\quad f\circ h\text{ is onto.}$$