# Find continuous functions that satisfy $f(f(x))=x$ over the reals.

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

I'm looking for a method to solve:

$$f(f(x))=x$$

Where $f$ is defined for $x \in R$

So far by inverting both sides I have:

$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

Which means that my function should be symmetrical over $y=x$. I may "guess" the functions:

$y=x$

$y=c-x$

However I'm wondering is there a way to solve this without "guessing".

Comment: $f(x)=c-x$ is also a solution.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla It's not - point $(0,1)$ belongs to this line, but $(1,0)$ doesn't.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46635/examples-of-involutions-on-mathbbr

Comment: Wow how did I miss that. I was thinking parrellel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions satisfying this property are known as [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29#Involution_throughout_the_fields_of_mathematics). See the article for many examples in various fields. You are correct about the symmetry condition.

Edit: I should add that there are unaccountably infinitely many of such functions (even restricting to continuous functions).