# Longer chains of adjoints :-)

Tags: order-theory, adjoint-functors, galois-connections

The first question:

Is in true that there exist chains of Galois connections (let's limit to Galois connections between posets) of arbitrary lengths $n$?

$F_0(a) \leq b$ if and only if $a \leq F_1(b)$; ...; $F_{n-1}(a) \leq b$ if and only if $a \leq F_n(b)$.

Then (as it is well known) $F_i(a) = \min \{ c \mid a \leq F_{i+1}(c) \}$.

Second question:

What about (which properties it has?) continuing this chain for $i<0$ if we instead require the weaker condition: $F_i(a) = \inf \{ c \mid a \leq F_{i+1}(c) \}$?

And finally: What's about generalizing this to arbitrary adjoint functors?

Answer (score 1):

### This sent me down a rabbit hole; thanks! ;)

You last two questions seem unclear to me.

However, for the first question: YES

For example, suppose `f, g` are inverse functions, ie
`f x = y  ≡  x = g y`. Then this statement means that they
are Galois Connected in the discrete order, ie equality `=`.

Let `Fₙ` be `f` if `n = 0 mod 2` and `g` otherwise.
Then, `Fₙ x ≤ y  ≡  x ≤ Fₙ₊₁ y` and this is a chain ;)

---

Perhaps you wanted an example in the non-discrete order?

No probs: take `Fₙ` to be the  identity function ;)

---

Perhaps you wanted an example in the non-discrete order
and with the non-identity function?

No probs: pick your favourite isotonic
(`x ≤ y  ≡ f x ≤ f y`) and involutive (`f ∘ f = id`) function `f`,
then define `Fₙ` to be `f`.

Indeed, we have `Fₙ x ≤ y  ≡  x ≤ Fₙ₊₁ y` as follows:

```
  Fₙ x ≤ y
≡     “definition of Fₙ”
  f x ≤ y
≡     “isotonicity of f”
  f (f x) ≤ f y
≡     “f involoutive”
  x ≤ f y
≡     “definition of Fₙ₊₁”  
  x ≤ Fₙ₊₁ y
```

Usually involutions tend to swap the order, and in some contexts
this is in-fact a definition of Galois Connection!! Weird..

( “A Glimpse Into The Wonderland Of Involutions”,
http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/education/wiener.pdf )

Anyhow, examples include

• boolean negation: `¬ p ⇒ q  ≡ p ⇐ ¬ q`

• additive inverse:  `- x ≤ y  ≡ x ≥ - y`

• multiplicative inverse: `1 / x ≤ y  ≡  x ≥ 1 / y`

• the previous two: `1 / x ⊑ y  ≡ x ⊑ 1 / y`
  where `a ⊑ b ∶≡ -a ≤ b`

• The above examples give a more general approach that avoids
  the flipping of the order:
  if `f` is an involution, then so is its “conjugate” `F x ≔ - f ( - x)`
  ---note that this applies to the three above, just use the appropriate negation
  operator ;)

Moreover, if `f` is isotonic then so is `F`! Neato ;)

• `F x ≔ a + (x - a)⁻¹` for any `a`, of course for domain we need `x ≠ a`;
  like the above, this is order-reversing GC: `F x ≤ y  ≡  x ≥ F y`.
  (src: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46814/80406 )

In-fact, this construction can be applied repetitively to yield new involutions:
  if `f` is an involution, then so is `F x ≔ f(x - a) + a`;
  moreover, if `f` is isotonic then so is `F`! Neato ;)

The above `general construction` are really instances of Babbage's Construction:
if `f` is an involution then so is
  `F ≔ φ⁻¹ ∘ f ∘ φ` for any invertible function `Φ`.
  (Src: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007270?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents )

Moreover, if `f` and `φ` are isotonic then so is `F`!

Finally, before I leave you, consider this the more common or familiar is exponentiation and logarithms
functions. Both are monotonic and are inverses, whence they are isotonic.
( `f x ≔ aˣ` is isotonic and so is `g x ≔ logₐ x`, for `a > 1`. )
Then `F x ≔ logₐ( (aˣ + d) / (aˣ - d) )` is isotonic if `d < 0` otherwise flips-order (or so I claim!).
Moreover, `F` is probably involution; I haven't checked.
Anyhow, here's the challenge: is this scenario an instance of Babbage's Construction? Or, can you generalise this to arbitrary monotone bijection pairs? ;)

Good night!

Comment: My main question was: if we **define** $F_i(a) = \inf \{ c \mid a \leq F_{i+1}(c) \}$, what will be the properties of $F_i(a)$ for $i<0$ (when we go outside of the familiar land of Galois connections).

Comment: (it is interesting in the assumption that $F_{i-1}$ is not an adjoint of $F_0$)