# Functional equation $f^{-1}(-x) = -f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations, inverse-function

Is there a way to find all analytic functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which are a solution of the functional equation (where $f^{-1}$ denotes inverse of the function) $$f^{-1}(-x)=-f(x)$$ with the additional condition $$\left. \frac{df}{dx} \right|_{x=0}=1?$$

Comment: By $f^{-1}$ you mean $\frac{1}{f}$ ?

Comment: No, I mean the inverse of $f$.

Comment: If you call $g=-f$ you obtain the functional equation $g(g(x))=x$, $g'(0)=-1$

Comment: @Gae.S.: Indeed. So $g$ is an involution with $g'(0) = -1$.

Comment: Conversely, if $g$ is an involution with $g'(0)=-1$ then $-g$ satisfies the conditions in the question. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46635/examples-of-involutions-on-mathbbr/2437503#2437503) characterizes continuous involutions on $\mathbb R$. By applying this characterization to a power series around $0$, maybe something intelligent could be said about the function.